# SPServices Grid view- SharePoint Multiple line column values to display in text-box

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spservices, html, spgridview

I have created Multi-line column in **SharePoint list**.

And using **spservice**, I have created grid view to display values like below:

[image]

when I select date, it retrieve values from SharePoint list and display in grid view. Here only Hours and Comments are only editable in gridview.

**Everything works fine.**

Only Comments can't retrieve from `SharePoint list`.

Finally I have changed in SharePoint list from **Rich Text to Plain Text**.

It display only one word before space like below:

[image]

In comment field values is more than `100 characters with spaces`. But it shows only one word as output.

Here is code to retrieve values:

```
$().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "RCCP Timecard",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ItemCreationDate' /><Value Type='Text'>" + TodayFilterdate + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Category' /><FieldRef Name='Subcategory' /><FieldRef Name='Platform' /><FieldRef Name='Function' /><FieldRef Name='Hours' /><FieldRef Name='Comments' /><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $("#myGridView").html('');
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {           
                    var RnDTitle = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                    var RnDCategory = $(this).attr("ows_Category");
                    var RnDSubcategory = $(this).attr("ows_Subcategory");
                    var RnDPlatform = $(this).attr("ows_Platform");
                    var RnDFunction = $(this).attr("ows_Function");
                    var RnDHours = $(this).attr("ows_Hours");
                    var RnDComments = $(this).attr("ows_Comments");
                    var RnDID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                    var newHours = '<input style="width:60px" id="UpdateHours' + rowIndex + '" value=' + RnDHours + ' class="UpdateHours" type="number"/>';
                    var newComments = '<input type="textarea" style="height:60px;" id="UpdateComments' + rowIndex + '" value=' + RnDComments + ' class="UpdateComments" />';
                    var newbutton = '<input id=' + RnDID + ' name="Updatebutton' + RnDID + '" class="update-allocation" type="button" value="Update" onclick="UpdateListItemss(this);"/>';
                    var newDeletebutton = '<input id=' + RnDID + ' name="Deletebutton' + RnDID + '" type="button" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteListItemss(this);"/>';
                    $("#myGridView").append("<tr align='center'>" +
                        "<td style='width:11.1%; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + RnDTitle + "</td>" +
                        "<td style='width:11.1%; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + RnDCategory + "</td>" +
                        "<td style='width:11.1%; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + RnDSubcategory + "</td>" +
                        "<td style='width:11.1%; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + RnDPlatform + "</td>" +
                        "<td style='width:11.1%; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + RnDFunction + "</td>" + 
                        "<td style='width:11.1%; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + newHours + "</td>" + 
                        "<td style='width:11.1%;text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + newComments + "</td>" + 
                        "<td style='width:11.1%;text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px;'>" + newbutton + "</td>" +
                        "<td style='width:11.1%;text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;'>" + newDeletebutton + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                });
            }
   });
```

**Please modify and help me. Where am getting error in code?**

> Present columns in **SharePoint List**:
>
> Hours: Single of Text,
>
> Comments: Multiple line of Text(Plain Text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its occurs because you are missing **quotes** when adding comment data.
 
Use below code,

```
var newComments = '<input type="textarea" style="height:60px;" id="UpdateComments' + rowIndex + '" value="' + RnDComments + '" class="UpdateComments" />';
```

instead of this,

```
var newComments = '<input type="textarea" style="height:60px;" id="UpdateComments' + rowIndex + '" value=' + RnDComments + ' class="UpdateComments" />';
```